# With how many beings has Fry had "relations"?

Tags: futurama

Fry had a convoluted love life, if his relation with Leela wasn't complicated enough, he also managed the outstanding feat of being his own grandfather.

I lost the count somewhere and his [Love life section](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fry_%28Futurama%29#Love_life) on Wikipedia seems to be incomplete, as his grandmother is missing.

With how many <strike>women</strike> beings has Fry been intimate?

Comment: How could Wikipedia forget that he did the nasty in the pasty?

Comment: @Keen - Would that not be "past-y"? Doing the nasty in a [pasty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pasty) would be messy and inconvenient

Comment: @user1027 - Verily!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The [Infosphere](http://theinfosphere.org/Philip_J._Fry#Relationships) lists 12 "beings" Fry has had a relationship of some sort with:

- [Leela](http://theinfosphere.org/Fry-Leela_relationship)
- [Colleen](http://theinfosphere.org/Colleen): A former peace officer.
- [21st-century girl](http://theinfosphere.org/21st-century_girl): Never named but they went on a date. Her appearance at his ["funeral"](http://theinfosphere.org/The_Sting) suggests it was more than just a "date".
- [Morgan Proctor](http://theinfosphere.org/Morgan_Proctor): A bureaucrat who "fraternized" him.
- [Michelle](http://theinfosphere.org/Michelle): His girlfriend from the past, who was also frozen and awakened in the future.
- [Ornik](http://theinfosphere.org/Ornik): An Amazonian who *attempted* to snu-snu him.
- [Petunia](http://theinfosphere.org/Petunia): [Bender's dating service](http://theinfosphere.org/Put_Your_Head_on_My_Shoulder) hooked her up on a date with him. Her appearance at his ["funeral"](http://theinfosphere.org/The_Sting) suggests it was more than just a "date".
- [Amy](http://theinfosphere.org/Amy)
- [Radiator](http://theinfosphere.org/Radiator): Fry made out with it thinking it was a "radiator woman from the radiator planet".
- [Yivo](http://theinfosphere.org/Yivo): A planet-sized alien from another universe.
- [Mildred Fry](http://theinfosphere.org/Mildred_Fry): His own grandmother.
- [Umbriel](http://theinfosphere.org/Umbriel): A mermaid from the lost city of Atlanta.

There are actually a couple more not mentioned in the above list:

- [Lucy Liubot](http://theinfosphere.org/Liubot#Liubot): A robot with the appearance and personality of Lucy Liu.
- [Edna](http://theinfosphere.org/Edna): A Decapodian who was briefly infatuated with Fry.

One more,often overlooked:
- [The Mayor's Wife](http://theinfosphere.org/Transcript:Ghost_in_the_Machines): "It sure was nice of the Mayor's wife to have sex with me" Fry upon returning from the Parade Day parade

Comment: is Radiator a "beings"?

Comment: @DavRob60: That's why it's in quotes. ;)

Comment: That radiator sounds *hot!*

Comment: "Her caviar is on your neck!"

Comment: @DavRob60  Note that the radiator was also at the funeral!

Comment: I'd suggest adding countless Amazonians to the list, because the final shot of Amazon women in the mood shows Fry and Zapp in pelvic casts and suggests that they indeed did snu-snu quite a lot.

Comment: @Lego Stormtroopr When the fembot names the groups, you could probably count the number of "small women".

Comment: -1 I assume that you have never actually been to a funeral: 'fucked the deceased' turns out not to be a common requisite.

Comment: @Lexible no one used the word "fucked" except you (i.e. he only made out with the radiator!). The group of beings sitting together at Fry's funeral are indeed strongly suggested to be most of his ex partners - we know for sure that some of them are (they even comment about his sexual performance).

Answer (score 7):

During Season 4, Episode 12, "The Sting," they show a funeral for Fry, complete with mourners in the back. You see a total of about 5 women sitting back there.  His ex-girlfriend that followed him to the future, the woman who took over for Hermes, an Amazonian woman, the old lady that's always smoking, and a 5th that I don't remember.  I also know that Fry dated Amy, and, as you mentioned ,his grandmother.  So altogether I would go with at least 7 affairs before finally getting with Leela.

[image: Attendees of Fry's funeral]

I don't remember his affair with the radiator, but from the image you can see (from right to left)

1) the amazonian's arm
2) the 20th century ex-girlfriend
3) Morgan Proctor (the woman who took Hermes job)
4) someone I don't recognize
5) Smoking woman(was setup with Fry by Bender when his head was attached to Amy's shoulder)
6) radiator

Comment: Woah woah woah. Spoiler alert. Fry went to the future?

Comment: whoops forgot I needed those.

Comment: The 5th was a radiator.

Comment: Wasn't the fifth a radiator?

Comment: not sure as I can't find a good screen shot from this part of the episode

Comment: @chcuk I added a screenshot for you but since it's your answer I'll let you modify it in response to the screengrab.

Comment: This should help you remember the radiator http://theinfosphere.org/Radiator